# 70/80s TV show/movie, group with powers gained by objects (rings/pendants/medallions?)

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I have a memory of a 70s-80s TV show or movie with a small group of people who have powers given by objects (medallions?). I recall a scene where they are in jail without their magic objects but somehow retrieve them.

I don't know if it's related but I also remember a scene on an icy lake with ice  vehicles of some sort (ice sailboats?) and a beheading by sword.  I'm not sure that's related  but it's in my brain and they feel linked.  When I was a kid I always thought it was *Ice Pirates* or maybe *Time Bandits*.  I looked at *The Phoenix* (TV Show) and found he has an amulet that gives him powers and in the pilot he's in jail for a bit but I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already; could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, where did you watch this, was it a foreign production?

Comment: Hey Jenayah!  I watched it in the US. I don't know if it might be a foreign production. I'm sure it wasn't dubbed and it was in english.   I've been poring over IMDB and Google this week trying to find it, and working the brain for more memories but that's all I have right now.  I looked at The Phoenix (TV Show) and found he has an amulet that gives him powers and in the pilot he's in jail for a bit but I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can (and should :) ) edit what you said above into the question, so that the info is gathered in the question rather than scattered in the comments.

Comment: *Misfits of Science* is another show around that time that had people with powers, but it's not from objects.

Comment: I came across Misfits of Science in my searches as well.  I am thinking whatever I saw was a TV movie or some particular episode of a show. So hard to find.